# Three.js : GLTF loading but not appearing

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

I'm trying to load GLTF into Three.js but it doesn't show up on the screen. I'm new to Three.js, so I've tried many ways but nothing works. There are no errors appearing in the Chrome developer window, just a white screen. Anyone know a solution?

Also My gltf file opens fine in the gltf viewer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>gltfExample01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/three.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/stats.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/dat.gui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../libs/glTFLoader.js" />
    <style>
        body {
            /* set margin to 0 and overflow to hidden, to go fullscreen */
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Div which will hold the Output -->
    <div id="WebGL-output"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init() {
            var scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
            scene.add(camera);

            var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

            renderer.setClearColor(new THREE.Color(0xEEEEEE, 1.0));
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
            renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;

            camera.position.x = -30;
            camera.position.y = 40;
            camera.position.z = 30;
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);

            // add the output of the renderer to the html element
            document.getElementById("WebGL-output").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
            loader.load(
                // resource URL
                './scene01.gltf',
                // called when the resource is loaded
                function ( gltf ) {

                    scene.add( gltf.scene );

                    gltf.animations; // Array<THREE.AnimationClip>
                    gltf.scene; // THREE.Group
                    gltf.scenes; // Array<THREE.Group>
                    gltf.cameras; // Array<THREE.Camera>
                    gltf.asset; // Object

                }
            );

            function render() {
                // render using requestAnimationFrame
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            render();
        }
        window.onload = init

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

PS. I'll attach chrome screen pictures.

[Chrome screen showing Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OP2zB.png)

[Chrome screen showing console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSJK2.png)

PS. I'll attach the contents of the glTF file just in case.

```
{
  "asset": {
    "version": "2.0",
    "generator": "THREE.GLTFExporter"
  },
  "scenes": [
    {
      "name": "Scene",
      "nodes": [
        0,
        1,
        4
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scene": 0,
  "nodes": [
    {
      "name": "AmbientLight"
    },
    {
      "name": "AmbientLight"
    },
    {
      "matrix": [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        2.3733431490050236,
        0.5964163550565602,
        5.436433345955958,
        1
      ],
      "name": "Box",
      "mesh": 0
    },
    {
      "matrix": [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        2.6066889361693835,
        0.5777642421996207,
        4.790873598688476,
        1
      ],
      "name": "Box",
      "mesh": 1
    },
    {
      "matrix": [
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        1,
        0,
        1.577277964727821,
        -0.2596547250878648,
        4.688496925702815,
        1
      ],
      "name": "Box",
      "mesh": 0,
      "children": [
        2,
        3
      ]
    }
  ],
  "bufferViews": [
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 0,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 12
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 288,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 12
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 576,
      "byteLength": 192,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 8
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 768,
      "byteLength": 72,
      "target": 34963
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 840,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 12
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 1128,
      "byteLength": 288,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 12
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 1416,
      "byteLength": 192,
      "target": 34962,
      "byteStride": 8
    },
    {
      "buffer": 0,
      "byteOffset": 1608,
      "byteLength": 72,
      "target": 34963
    }
  ],
  "buffers": [
    {
      "byteLength": 1680,
      "uri": "data:application/octet-stream;base64,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"
    }
  ],
  "accessors": [
    {
      "bufferView": 0,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        0.5,
        0.5,
        0.5
      ],
      "min": [
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
        -0.5
      ],
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 1,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        1,
        1,
        1
      ],
      "min": [
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
      ],
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 2,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        1,
        1
      ],
      "min": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "type": "VEC2"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 3,
      "componentType": 5123,
      "count": 36,
      "max": [
        23
      ],
      "min": [
        0
      ],
      "type": "SCALAR"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 4,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        0.5,
        0.5,
        0.5
      ],
      "min": [
        -0.5,
        -0.5,
        -0.5
      ],
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 5,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        1,
        1,
        1
      ],
      "min": [
        -1,
        -1,
        -1
      ],
      "type": "VEC3"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 6,
      "componentType": 5126,
      "count": 24,
      "max": [
        1,
        1
      ],
      "min": [
        0,
        0
      ],
      "type": "VEC2"
    },
    {
      "bufferView": 7,
      "componentType": 5123,
      "count": 36,
      "max": [
        23
      ],
      "min": [
        0
      ],
      "type": "SCALAR"
    }
  ],
  "materials": [
    {
      "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
        "baseColorFactor": [
          0.3411764705882353,
          0.23921568627450981,
          0.23921568627450981,
          1
        ],
        "metallicFactor": 0.5,
        "roughnessFactor": 0.5
      },
      "emissiveFactor": [
        0.6784313725490196,
        0.2823529411764706,
        0.2823529411764706
      ]
    },
    {
      "pbrMetallicRoughness": {
        "metallicFactor": 0,
        "roughnessFactor": 1
      },
      "emissiveFactor": [
        0.16862745098039217,
        1,
        0
      ]
    }
  ],
  "meshes": [
    {
      "primitives": [
        {
          "mode": 4,
          "attributes": {
            "POSITION": 0,
            "NORMAL": 1,
            "TEXCOORD_0": 2
          },
          "indices": 3,
          "material": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "primitives": [
        {
          "mode": 4,
          "attributes": {
            "POSITION": 4,
            "NORMAL": 5,
            "TEXCOORD_0": 6
          },
          "indices": 7,
          "material": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And this is image of my glTF File.

[glTF image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFyq.png)

Comment: Is your gltf file textured and/or with materials on? Maybe you see a blank screen just because your mesh is added with the default white material. You could try assigning a material to the mesh while loading it.

Comment: Oh... All materials are set to red as MESHLAMBERTMATERIAL. I created and exported this GLTF using the editor of Three.js homepage.

Comment: Are you sure that your scene works fine? I mean, if you add a simple cube, does it render correctly? On the other hand, are you sure that your loading callback gets called? If you print something to console right after scene.add(gltf.scene), does it print? I ask these because the gltf loading procedure seems correct to me.

Comment: I checked as you said and it's not working. I tried adding it after the camera.position setting, but it didn't work either. What's the problem?

Comment: Actually, I just tried your whole code and it works fine, I can see the gltf and I can see any mesh I add to the scene... Are you sure that Chrome does not warn you of anything? I see a warning about a deprecated function when running you code.

Comment: I added a picture of the chrome to the post. Does it help? My chrome still has a white screen.

Comment: Since you're using `MeshLambertMaterial`, you need a light source, try `scene.add(new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x404040 ))`,

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't work. Just same. I have attached the content and image of my gltF file to the post. Would that help?

Comment: Your problem is not in the gltf, since you set the renderer background color to grey but your screen is white. I think you may have some problem with your html/css setup, try messing around with those elements. For example, in the elements of your page, the <body> seems to be empty...

Comment: Oh... As you said, there was a problem with <style>. Now I solved this problem thanks to you. But there is another problem. I'll post a separate question on this one. Thx :)